# Broad Design Implementation: PHP, MySQL, Knockout

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, knockout.js

Spent the last few weeks learning MySQL and PHP. Then I learned some basic knockout.js and I'm rewriting a lot of things.'

Just wanted to check before I go further if this is the most efficient way of doing things with PHP/MySQL/Knockout.js-

Pages are php with Knockout which is pulling and pushing data via ajax/Json to separate php files which then push to MySQL. The login system is PHP & MySQL. And I'm using $_SESSION variables to limit content (its a project management system) to what each user is allowed to access.

Is this the current way of doing things? Or am I still behind the times

thanks!
-newb

Answer (score 0):

knockout is the way to go, maybe in combination with jquery in the client side you are good to go, but i recommend you to use a php framework for the server side like codeigniter, zend, symfony there are lots of them, i am currently using codeigniter + jquery + knockout and is boosting me a lot. hope this will help you